# Can't check key distribution with FNV-1 algorithm

Tags: c#, azure, hash, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

As recommended by a lot of places, I am using the FNV-1 method to generate my partition keys for a Service Fabric cluster with 5 partitions as below:

```
[
  {
    "lowKey": -5534023222112865000,
    "highKey": -1844674407370955300,
    "id": "92b4c32e-cb3c-432f-aea0-4579fc72850c",
    "kind": 2
  },
  {
    "lowKey": 5534023222112865000,
    "highKey": 9223372036854776000,
    "id": "dd9b084d-88fa-4773-94d9-f634d22a2c03",
    "kind": 2
  },
  {
    "lowKey": -9223372036854776000,
    "highKey": -5534023222112865000,
    "id": "d7322e52-cf1e-47c2-b713-e983f443b533",
    "kind": 2
  },
  {
    "lowKey": -1844674407370955300,
    "highKey": 1844674407370955300,
    "id": "dfe2f994-bdc7-4b32-b54f-78a0245e4c4c",
    "kind": 2
  },
  {
    "lowKey": 1844674407370955300,
    "highKey": 5534023222112865000,
    "id": "6ad81ffb-5f3c-48ba-91d9-e65b23c528a4",
    "kind": 2
  }
]
```

I want to check what the distribution of my data is like.

However, I can't see how to do this because the numbers are so large.

I am assuming that I have to use LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" for this?

If so, these numbers are too big/small for me to process in either SQL or C# (C# because the constants are too big).

Is there a way around this?  I get into overflow issues if I try to save these values in my database.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(LowKey BIGINT, HighKey BIGINT, TotalITems INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl(LowKey, HighKey, TotalITems) VALUES (5534023222112865000, 9223372036854776000, 0)
INSERT INTO @tbl(LowKey, HighKey, TotalITems) VALUES (-9223372036854776000, -5534023222112865000, 0)

INSERT INTO @tbl(LowKey, HighKey, TotalITems) VALUES (-5534023222112865000, -1844674407370955300, 0)
INSERT INTO @tbl(LowKey, HighKey, TotalITems) VALUES (-1844674407370955300, 1844674407370955300, 0)
INSERT INTO @tbl(LowKey, HighKey, TotalITems) VALUES (1844674407370955300, 5534023222112865000, 0)
```

The first 2 lines fail with the error

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 168
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.
```

Here is the logic I use to see what the partitions are:

```
[ActionName("GetPartitions")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPartitionsAsync()
{
   var result = new List<ServicePartitionInformation>();
   ServicePartitionList partitions = await FabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(FullServiceName).ConfigureAwait(false);

   foreach (var partition in partitions)
   {
       result.Add(partition.PartitionInformation);
   }

   return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Fabric can use a UniformInt64Partition. That means a minimum low of -9223372036854775808 and a maximum high of 9223372036854775807.

You can check that using

```
Console.WriteLine(long.MinValue);
Console.WriteLine(long.MaxValue);
```

So your json is incorrect. For example, -9223372036854776000 is not a valid long/Int64 value.

> I am assuming that I have to use LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" for this?
>
> If so, these numbers are to big/small for me to process in either SQL or C# (C# because the constants are too big)

Can't be, these are the defaults for a stateful service which is Int64 based.

```
<Service Name="Stateful1" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
  <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="Stateful1Type" TargetReplicaSetSize="[Stateful1_TargetReplicaSetSize]" MinReplicaSetSize="[Stateful1_MinReplicaSetSize]">
    <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[Stateful1_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
  </StatefulService>
</Service>
```

When I run your code against a new default stateful service I get

```
[
    {
        "LowKey": 5534023222112865485,
        "HighKey": 9223372036854775807,
        "Id": "ef982303-dd13-49f0-ad3c-5de7428eccad",
        "Kind": 2
    },
    {
        "LowKey": -1844674407370955161,
        "HighKey": 1844674407370955161,
        "Id": "e2e5f51b-d3f5-4381-b7ff-6267124d0adb",
        "Kind": 2
    },
    {
        "LowKey": -5534023222112865484,
        "HighKey": -1844674407370955162,
        "Id": "4715db41-124a-4eee-b5b9-2587256ed6e1",
        "Kind": 2
    },
    {
        "LowKey": -9223372036854775808,
        "HighKey": -5534023222112865485,
        "Id": "10e9d445-53e0-4f27-9434-0ea5621ac188",
        "Kind": 2
    },
    {
        "LowKey": 1844674407370955162,
        "HighKey": 5534023222112865484,
        "Id": "687c1c4d-9fc1-4574-a916-66ac5ebfed25",
        "Kind": 2
    }
]
```

As you can see your highkey 9223372036854776000 and lowkey -9223372036854776000 are invalid and are not in my generated json. Not sure where that comes from then.

My code to reproduce:

```
    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = new List<ServicePartitionInformation>();
        ServicePartitionList partitions = await new FabricClient().QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(Context.ServiceName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var partition in partitions)
        {
            result.Add(partition.PartitionInformation);
        }

        var info = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        Console.WriteLine(info);
    }
```

Comment: Yep it matches what you have there apart from I dont have the ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess" bit - I can add that I wasnt really sure if it is needed

Comment: hiNo, that is not really necessary. Let me try to reproduce this.

Comment: @Paul I can't reproduce this, see updates answer. Can you try add a new stateful service and run the code against that one?

Comment: I agree, if I use your code in my service I get these partitions.  But I cant use this principle. I have a gateway service which is responsible for working out the partition then doing the call.  So not sure where to take this now?

Comment: ok I deleted everything and did it again now I do get a match :)  I think I will mark this as an answer - the database side I was able to get around by using FLOAT instead of BIGINT.  I know float has precision issues, but these numbers are not fractional so should be ok?

Comment: should be ok, but still very strange where that  wrong high key / low key comes from. You could just alter the db script so only the valid high and lowkey is stored, knowing that service fabric won't drop requetst since it is limited to the valid high and low keys.